# Have there been female legionaries or gladiators?

Tags: ancient-rome, gender, gladiators

Did ancient Rome ever have female legionaries or gladiators? Either officially or because they disguised themselves as man would count for an answer.

If not, has the idea ever been discussed in ancient Rome? Was the exclusion of women from those roles codified in law or something similar?

Comment: Wikipedia has a page on [female gladiators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gladiatrix).

Comment: Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions. Please revise your question to document your preliminary research.

Answer (score 4):

While the Romans certainly encountered warrior women when fighting against the various Barbarian tribes, women were not allowed to serve in the army in any official capacity. Women certainly did follow the army as part of the horde of camp followers however that decreased after the reforms of Marius.  As to whether a woman disguised herself as man to serve there's no evidence of that yet either. It's highly unlikely that a Roman woman even one of any class would entertain the idea of being a solider either.

As to female gladiators yes there were female gladiators called gladiatrices however they were uncommon and little is known about them specifically.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women_in_ancient_warfare
https://www.bbc.co.uk/bitesize/topics/zwmpfg8/articles/zqbnfg8